# Cargo: Delete a File from Container

Tags: apache-tomee, cargo

**Is it possible to delete a Library from the container/application-server used by cargo?**

I am using TomEE, but always exclude the Library lib\slf4j-jdk14-1.7.5.jar because I am  using Logback overall in the container. Now I want to use Cargo for testing purposes, but through artifactInstaller it downloads the complete Tomee-1.6.0 package and I do not see, how I could delete the slf4j-jdk14 dependency.

Is there a possibility within the Cargo-Maven plugin? 
Or perhaps a maven configuration task?

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
<artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.4.8</version>
<configuration>
    <container>
        <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
        <artifactInstaller>
            <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-tomee</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <classifier>plus</classifier>
        </artifactInstaller>
        <timeout>3000000</timeout>
        <systemProperties>
            <environment>ci</environment>
        </systemProperties>
        <log/>
        <output/>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>aqapi</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </container>

    <configuration>
        <properties>
            <cargo.servlet.port>${custom.http.port}</cargo.servlet.port>
            <cargo.tomcat.ajp.port>${custom.ajp.port}</cargo.tomcat.ajp.port>
            <cargo.rmi.port>${custom.rmi.port}</cargo.rmi.port>
            <cargo.jvmargs>-Xms256m -Xmx1500m -XX:MaxPermSize=384m</cargo.jvmargs>
        </properties>
        <configfiles>
            <configfile>
                <file>src/test/tomee/conf/tomee.xml</file>
                <todir>conf</todir>
            </configfile>
            <configfile>
                <file>src/test/tomee/logging.properties</file>
                <todir>conf</todir>
            </configfile>
            <configfile>
                <file>src/test/tomee/logback.xml</file>
                <todir>shared/classes</todir>
            </configfile>
        </configfiles>
    </configuration>

    <deployables>
        <deployable>
            <groupId>de.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-war</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>
            <properties>
                <context>test-war</context>
            </properties>
        </deployable>
    </deployables>

</configuration>
```